# Failed to define class org.springframework.beans.PropertyAccessException

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, aop, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to do full-publish of a war file into WildFly 18 server, I was able to succesfully deploy before, but probably after a project update and eclipse update, I'm getting this error now:

```
2019-11-13 18:12:09,873 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 400) Failed to define class org.springframework.beans.PropertyAccessException in Module "deployment.pickingWEBMedalfa.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/beans/PropertyAccessException (Module "deployment.pickingWEBMedalfa.war" from Service Module Loader): org/springframework/core/ErrorCoded
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:832)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:832)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:832)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:731)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    at org.springframework.beans.PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(PropertyAccessorFactory.java:37)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:124)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:180)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:305)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:585)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:556)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:598)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)

2019-11-13 18:12:09,875 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 4) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"pickingWEBMedalfa.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/beans/ConversionNotSupportedException (Module \"deployment.pickingWEBMedalfa.war\" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/beans/TypeMismatchException (Module \"deployment.pickingWEBMedalfa.war\" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/beans/PropertyAccessException (Module \"deployment.pickingWEBMedalfa.war\" from Service Module Loader): org/springframework/core/ErrorCoded
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/beans/ConversionNotSupportedException (Module \"deployment.pickingWEBMedalfa.war\" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/beans/TypeMismatchException (Module \"deployment.pickingWEBMedalfa.war\" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/beans/PropertyAccessException (Module \"deployment.pickingWEBMedalfa.war\" from Service Module Loader): org/springframework/core/ErrorCoded"}}
2019-11-13 18:12:09,876 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = pickingWEBMedalfa.war_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
2019-11-13 18:12:09,876 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = pickingWEBMedalfa.war
2019-11-13 18:12:09,877 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = pickingWEBMedalfa.war_org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver_2_3
2019-11-13 18:12:09,954 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment pickingWEBMedalfa.war (runtime-name: pickingWEBMedalfa.war) in 79ms
2019-11-13 18:12:09,955 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 4) WFLYSRV0014: Replacement of deployment "pickingWEBMedalfa.war" by deployment "pickingWEBMedalfa.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"pickingWEBMedalfa.war\".undertow-deployment" => "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/beans/ConversionNotSupportedException (Module \"deployment.pickingWEBMedalfa.war\" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/beans/TypeMismatchException (Module \"deployment.pickingWEBMedalfa.war\" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/beans/PropertyAccessException (Module \"deployment.pickingWEBMedalfa.war\" from Service Module Loader): org/springframework/core/ErrorCoded
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/beans/ConversionNotSupportedException (Module \"deployment.pickingWEBMedalfa.war\" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/beans/TypeMismatchException (Module \"deployment.pickingWEBMedalfa.war\" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/beans/PropertyAccessException (Module \"deployment.pickingWEBMedalfa.war\" from Service Module Loader): org/springframework/core/ErrorCoded"}}
```

The pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
            <version>Cairo-SR8</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.activation</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.el</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-el-api_3.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.inject-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-interceptors-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr181-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-MR1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.management.j2ee</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-j2eemgmt-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.resource</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-connector-api_1.7_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.security.auth.message</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jaspi-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jsp-api_2.3_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.3_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.17.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
        <artifactId>undertow-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.27.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0-M1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
      <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
      <version>0.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
      <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
      <version>3.19.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.zenframework.z8.dependencies.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>dom4j-1.6.1</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <classifier>sources</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And the spring-servlet.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">
    <annotation-driven />
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <beans:property name="jndiName" value="java:/pickingWEB" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.medical.medalfa</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.medical.medalfa" />
    <beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
    </beans:bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

The project structure is:

[image: project structure]

Any further help is greatly apreciated.

Comment: Check if you can run your project on the command line with maven commands. If you can, delete the .project file and re-import the project. See if that works.

Comment: I tried with no success